# DRCSIM: VRC is Black and Gold

Tags: gazebo-camera

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I can understand why we would want Pittsburgh related Easter Eggs in all the VRC environments, but I am a little curious why the walls of the starting pens appear black with a yellow (gold?) stripe in the eyes of the robot. (Or at least the images as captured by the cameras).

Same for traffic cones, barrels, and the traffic sign. Wow, this is sweet, guys!

May I suggest an appropriate DRCSIM theme song? [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black\_and_Yellow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black%5C_and_Yellow)

Team Steel, Pittsburgh
Go Penguins
Go Steelers
Not so much, Pirates

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1708/drcsim:-vrc-is-black-and-gold/) by [cga](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/66/cga/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 223 on 2013-03-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

It's a bug of the "old" Gazebo. It's fixed in 1.5.

---

Originally posted by [ThomasK](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/16/thomask/) with karma: 508 on 2013-03-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1